# Getting a "Must declare scalar variable" error for DeleteCommand despite it working in UpdateCommand

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

My GridView has an UpdateCommand and DeleteCommand and I use a @ProjUID variable for both of them. It seems to work perfectly fine for UpdateCommand but breaks for DeleteCommand. There is virtually no differences between the two in the way I'm using it.

```
<asp:GridView ID="ProjectTable" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana,Arial" Font-Size="12px" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="PopulateProjectTable" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="250" AllowSorting="True" OnRowDataBound="ProjectTable_RowDataBound">
```

This is how I created my GridView. And then how I created the necessary columns for Edit and Delete...

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div style="white-space: nowrap;">
            <asp:LinkButton ID="editButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit">Edit</asp:LinkButton>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="deleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Visible="False" OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to DELETE?');" >Delete</asp:LinkButton>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <div style="white-space: nowrap;">
            <asp:LinkButton ID="BtnUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update">Update</asp:LinkButton>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="BtnCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel">Cancel</asp:LinkButton>
        </div>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="ProjUID" HeaderText="ProjUID" ItemStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" SortExpression="ProjUID" />
```

CSS for `hiddencol`...

```
.hiddencol 
{ 
    display: none; 
}
```

Finally, this is how my SQLDataSource is like...

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="PopulateProjectTable" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ODSConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="..."
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Pipeline] SET Project_Name = @Project_Name, Comment_Submission = @Comment_Submission, Hide_From = @Hide_From, LastModifiedDate = GETDATE(), LastModifiedby = USER WHERE ProjUID = @ProjUID and Internal_External = @Internal_External"
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Pipeline] WHERE ProjUID = @ProjUID">
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ProjUID"/>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Project_Name" Type="String"/>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Comment_Submission" Type="String"/>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Hide_From" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Internal_External"/>
        </UpdateParameters>
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ProjUID" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <SelectParameters>
            ...
        </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I have the same exact setup for `UpdateParameters` and it doesn't give me the "Must declare scalar variable `@ProjUID`" error like it does when I try to delete a row. What's going on?

Let me know if this is not enough information.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. I just needed to add:

```
 DataKeyNames="ProjUID"
```

If it is not an ideal solution or if it is **the** solution. Please let me know!

Comment: That's the right way to do it. With that in place, you can also remove your hidden column.

Answer (score 0):

If using an ODBC connect you cannot use named parameters.  Try this instead.

`DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Pipeline] WHERE ProjUID = ?">`